# C++ POO No se muestra correctamente la variable

Tags: c++, poo, variables

Estoy haciendo un programa de cobro y pago de servicios básicos en codeblocks

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class base { 
    private:
    //bienvenido
    char nick[30];
    //persona
    char opcion_persona;
    //menu
    int key;
    int opcion;
    //informacion
    int keyi;
    int opi;
    //salir
    char opcion_salir; 
    public:
    void bienvenido ();
    void persona ();
    void menu ();
    void informacion();
    void salir (); };

void base::bienvenido() {
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";   
    cout<<"<:: Sistema de Facturacion DFP ::>";     
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";     
    cout<<"> Bienvenido a Digital Fast Payment ";   
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";     
    cout<<"< Ingrese un nick: ";    
    cin.getline(nick, 15, '\n');    
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t"; }

void base::persona() {
    while (opcion_persona!='n' && opcion_persona!='j')
    {
        system ("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
        cout<<"<:: Sistema de Facturacion DFP ::>";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"> Hola "<<nick<<" usted es?";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"(n) Persona natural";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"(j) Persona juridica";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"< Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion_persona;
        if (opcion_persona!='n' && opcion_persona!='j')
        {
            cout<<"\n\t\t\t";
            cout<<"> Ingrese una opcion correcta";
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
        }
    } }

void base::menu() {
    base principal;
    while (key!=1)  
        {       system("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
        cout<<"<:: Sistema de Facturacion DFP ::>";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"> Menu de opciones";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"1 - Informacion";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"2 - Pago de servicios";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"3 - Salir";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"< Elija una opcion "<<nick<<": ";
        cin>>opcion;
        if (opcion!=1 && opcion!=2 && opcion!=3)        
        {           key=0;          
        cout<<"\n\t\t\t";           
        cout<<"< Elija una opcion de menu";             
        cin.get();          
        cin.get();      }       
        else        
        key=1;      
        switch (opcion)         
        {           case 1:
                {
                    principal.informacion();
                    key=0;
                    break;}             case 2:
                {
                    key=0;
                    break;}             case 3:
                {
                    principal.salir();
                    key=0;
                    break;}
        }

    }

}

void base::informacion() {
    base informacion;
    while (keyi!=1)     {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
        cout<<"<:: Sistema de Facturacion DFP ::>";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        //Aqui es el problema
        cout<<"> Aqui puede consultar los valores de los servicios "<<nick;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"1 - Luz";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"2 - Agua";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"3 - Telefono";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"4 - Internet";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"5 - Tv pagada";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"6 - Atras";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";
        cout<<"< Elija una opcion: ";
        cin>>opi;       if (opi!=1 && opi!=2 && opi!=3 && opi!=4 && opi!=5 && opi!=6)       {           keyi=0;             cout<<"\n\t\t\t";           cout<<"< Elija una opcion de menu";             cin.get();          cin.get();      }       else        keyi=1;         switch (opi)        {           case 1:
                {
                    keyi=0;
                    break;}             case 2:
                {
                    keyi=0;
                    break;}             case 3:
                {
                    keyi=0;
                    break;}             case 4:
                {
                    keyi=0;
                    break;}             case 5:
                {
                    keyi=0;
                    break;}             case 6:
                {
                    keyi=1;
                    break;}         }   }   keyi=0; }

void base::salir() {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
    cout<<"<:: Sistema de Facturacion DFP ::>";     
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";     
    cout<<"> "<<char(168)<<"Desea salir del programa?";                   
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t";             
    cout<<"< 0 para salir o cualquier tecla para regresar: ";
    cin>>opcion_salir;  
    if (opcion_salir=='0')  
    exit(0); }

int main () {
    base cuerpo;
    cuerpo.bienvenido();
    cuerpo.persona();
    cuerpo.menu();
    return 0; }
```

Mi problema es la variable *char nick[30]*, a la hora de ejecutar el programa y llegar al objeto *"principal.informacion"* no se muestra correctamente ¿Como lo arreglo?

Comment: Por cierto el programa no esta terminado, pero me he topado con este problema

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no se muestra correctamente? una buena idea sería editar tu código y colocar un comentario en la parte donde se presenta el error.

Comment: Listo ya lo aclare con un comentario en el codigo @Monpeco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void base::menu()
{
  base principal;
  // ...
  principal.informacion();
}
```

Si estás ejecutando una función de `base`, ¿por qué motivo estas creando un segundo objeto de tipo `base`?

`principal` es un objeto independiente y lo que hagas en dicho objeto no se verá reflejado en el objeto sobre el que estás ejecutando el método `menu`.

Un ejemplo para verlo mejor

```
class NoFunciona
{
  public:

    NoFunciona() : var(0)
    {}

    void Func()
    {
      NoFunciona objetoLocal;
      objetoLocal.Func2();
      std::cout << objetoLocal.var << '\n';
      std::cout << var << '\n';
    }

    void Func2()
    { var = 1; }
};

int main()
{
  NoFunciona objeto;
  objeto.Func();
}
```

En el ejemplo se ve el problema que tu tienes. Al crear un objeto nuevo, éste tiene su propio ciclo de vida y sus variables no son compartidas por el objeto contenedor. Cuidado con eso.

```
void base::menu()
{
  // ...
  informacion();
}
```

Con este simple cambio te debería funcionar esa parte.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @eferion, solucionaste mi problema, y gracias por explicarlo